# JPQL FROM section

Tags: java, jpa, jpql

I want to optimize the number of queries in the database. At the moment on REST the list of devices comes. Need to check if new devices have been added. Now it works like this: all devices for the current user are selected from the database and a check(with a list received from the request) for the presence of new devices. I want to translate all the work into a database and do something like this:

```
select p 
from :firstParam p 
where p.sdauId NOT IN (select t.id 
                       from Equipment t 
                       where t.owner.id = :secondParam)
```

Param ":firstParam" is a list of devices received from the request. ":secondParam" is a user id.

Can i use the section "from" like that? After reading the documentation and making many attempts to make a similar request, nothing came of it. I will be grateful for any tips on writing a request or approach to solving such a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Database object names (e.g. database, table, column names) cannot be bound using a placeholder in a prepared statement.  So, you'll have to hard code the name of the first table:

```
select p
from yourTable p    -- cannot use a parameter for table names
where p.sdauId NOT IN (select t.id from Equipment t where t.owner.id = :secondParam)
```

Comment: As the first parameter, I want to transfer the list of entities. But it is probably impossible. I started from the logic that if section "from" can have a nested query, then you can probably pass the list of entities

Comment: If you think you have the need to do this, then please reconsider your design and approach.